# Get number from string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field in oracle table. I want to get number value from value of field.
The field value like:

```json
{
  "id" : "02123",
  "pointAmount" : 4000,
  "transTypeId" : 1000129,
  "transId" : "123456"
}
```

Type of this field is varchar2. I want to get value 4000 of pointAmount to check condition. How can I do?

Comment: my field name is request, type is varchar and that json is string so I don't know how to get the string 4000 from my field

Answer (score 0):

Json_table is available since Oracle 12.1.0.2:

```
SELECT jt.*
FROM your_table t
JSON_TABLE(t.field, '$' 
COLUMNS
  (pointAmount number FORMAT JSON PATH '$.pointAmount')) AS jt;
```